# Print all Palindromic Subsequences in a given string (not distinct)

Tags: palindrome, subsequence

There are many problems of this kind on GFG like Count All Palindromic Subsequence in a given String. But I have not found this question anywhere:

```
Print all Palindromic Subsequences in a given string (not distinct).
```

I looked at [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-palindromic-subsequence-given-string/) on GFG and tried to test it for string "aba" for understanding and I found the ans as 5 but according to me, the possible palindromic subsequences are `{'a','b','a','aa'} and they are 4`.

```
So my question is why it is 5 and what is the fifth palindromic subsequence in "aba" that I am not able to find?
```

Because of this I am not able to understand the question Count All Palindromic Subsequence in a given String. Kindly help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `aba` is already a palindrome, it must be included in the set of all palindromic subsequences.

So the final answer would be: `{'a','b','a','aa','aba'}`.

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot. As I was so much into find one from it I forgot it itself is also Palindrome. Thanks a lot!